# Apply TAX to shipping programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store where I created a condition for applying fees when the product is in a certain category.
It is working well, but I would like to apply this tax on shipping.
The shipping fee setting in woocommerce is enabled. I was unable to find reference materials on the subject. Could someone help me, please?

This is the code I'm using to apply the tax class:

```
foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class('st-banheira-sem-hidro');
}
```

The admin config:
[image]

admin config tax

Tax works fine, but not calculate for shipping.

Comment: First this is about settings on the admin tax tables, where you can tick shipping option checkbox… Now you need to provide in your question your own real related code attempt, as your actual provided code is very poor and not really related…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, tks. I added a print with the rate class configuration. See that the option is checked, but it doesn't work. And I always have to recalculate orders manually.

This is all the code I have for applying the fee, and as I said, I have not found reference material for applying fees on shipping.

The condition that I created to apply the fee is very simple, based on the product category.

Comment: First you should provide that related code in your question and also your should provide in your question your own real related code attempt. Remember that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service. People will here will help on your code attempt issues.